# editing robots.txt in wordpress without plugin and without manual edits

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

I am trying to edit a robots.txt file in wordpress.  I can do so manually.  Is there an option in wordpress (without installing plugins) to edit robots.txt or one has to install a plugin for this purpose?

I will gladly close the question if deemed inappropriate for this prestigious forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built into WordPress to edit the robots.txt file directly.  You would either need to manually edit it, or use a plugin.

WordPress will automatically create the robots.txt for you.  If it is a matter of preventing bots from seeing some pages, I would suggest using a plugin called [Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/) which will help you with that.

For some information on this topic, You can check out [this great article](http://blogdum.com/how-to-edit-robots-txt-in-wordpress-113/).

Comment: I'd recommend checking out this: http://blogdum.com/how-to-edit-robots-txt-in-wordpress-113/

Comment: @ToddNestor I was just editing the post to add that article in there. :)

Comment: This blog is redirecting to aliexpress.

Comment: The blog is asking me to enable notifications to prove I am not a robot :) as if robots can't press allow!!!!!!!

Answer (score 18):

You DON'T need to:

- use plugin
- create a file

The first is excessive, the second gets in the way of WP and other plugins that need to update robots.txt.

I can't believe this isn't documented somewhere, but I finally figured it out:

WP has a robots.txt generation process, "robots_txt". If you hook a filter into this you can added stuff to robots **without a plugin** and **without adding a file**. Add something like this to your functions.php file:

```
add_filter('robots_txt', 'addToRoboText');

function addToRoboText($robotext) {
    $additions = "
# Added by filter in functions
User-agent: NinjaBot
Allow: /
";
    return $robotext . $additions;
}
```

This will append to your virtual robots.txt 'file' and other plugins, e.g. site-map plugins will be able to append also.

Notice, I didn't indent the lines intended for inclusion. The tabs/spaces become part of the string and indent the text in the robots file. I don't think it matters but it looks too messy for me.

Now, go to http://yourdomain/robots.txt and see how it looks!

Woo hoo!

Comment: Astonishing that this is not better documented.